# Need the entire chain of Child of a particular parent record in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database, parent-child

We want to get the total TREE structure (Down chain) of a particular record based on the ID from SQL Server.

This is my data table structure:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
CHILD_CODE      PARENT_CODE      CHILD_RANK      PARENT_RANK
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1               Null                  1          Null
2               1                     2          1
3               1                     2          1
4               1                     2          1
5               2                     3          2
6               2                     3          2
7               3                     3          2
8               5                     4          3
```

Here I need to have the entire child tree for a parent. Means if I give 2 as parent input it will give me all the child below it as a tree till the end.
example... 1

input > PARENT_CODE = 2

output >

```
----------------------------------------------
PARENT_CODE     CHILD_CODE      CHILD_RANK
----------------------------------------------
2               5               3
2               6               3
2               8               4
----------------------------------------------
```

Here we have used the CET like

```
; WITH rekurs AS (
   SELECT child_code, child_rank
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  parent_code = 2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ch.child_code, ch.child_rank
   FROM   tbl ch
   JOIN   rekurs r ON ch.parent_code = r.child_code
)
SELECT 2 AS PARENT_CODE, child_code, child_rank
FROM  CTE
```

We have already added this CTE in out program but here we are working on a large number of records and we are facing some problem. In this CTE we are passing a single `parent_code` for which we are getting all the child of that particular code.

Here we want to get all the child of 30,000 parent_code, which is taking so much times while we are passing the `parent_code` to CTE one by one in a for loop from C# program. Is there any  way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Why not pass in the ids using a table variable instead of calling one by one?

Comment: Solution suggested are good.This also prove that storing million of rows in parent-child relation manner are bad,because recursive query on million of records are really bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code

Suppose your table name is `data` then:

```
declare @input int =2
;with report as(
   select ChildCode,ParentCode,ChildRank,ParentRank
   from data
   where ParentCode = @input
   union all
   select d.ChildCode,d.ParentCode,d.ChildRank,d.ParentRank
   from data d
   inner join report r on d.ParentCode = r.ChildCode
 )

 select * from report
```

Here a working [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e08b8/2)

Result

```
ChildCode   ParentCode  ChildRank   ParentRank
5   2   3   2
6   2   3   2
8   5   4   3
```

**Edit** based on the comments below

**Explanation**

1. you can create a user defined table type

   `create type ParentInputs as table(ParentCode int)`
2. You pass the table type parameter to the query

**Query**

```
;with report as(
   select ChildCode,d.ParentCode,ChildRank,ParentRank
   from @data d
   inner join @input p on d.ParentCode = p.ParentCode
   union all
   select d.ChildCode,d.ParentCode,d.ChildRank,d.ParentRank
   from @data d
   inner join report r on d.ParentCode = r.ChildCode
 )
 select * from report order by ParentCode
```

For the sake of the demo, I created a parameter table instead of the table type, kindly find the working [demo](http://rextester.com/TZCENV49230)

Result for ParentCode (2,3)

```
ChildCode   ParentCode  ChildRank   ParentRank
5   2   3   2
6   2   3   2
7   3   3   2
8   5   4   3
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: +1 for a working solution, but the semicolon belongs at the end of the previous line, not at the start of the line in front of `with`

Comment: @AshleyPillay for the semicolon technically you're right, but it is common practice to add it in front of with to be sure not to forget, since it is mandatory to have a trailing semicolon before that specific word, while most of the others do not need that

Comment: It's common practice because most people don't understand the error message SQL Server throws about expecting a semicolon before `with` so they just toss in a semicolon without understanding it's the statement terminator in the ANSI SQL spec. We should try to follow the ANSI spec & get used to terminating all SQL statements with semicolons. (Rant over :)

Comment: @Monah, i think your answer is just adding a parameter but not helping them in solving the issue to have many parents for each call

Answer (score 1):

does the following could work for you:

```
; WITH rekurs AS (
   SELECT parent_code Root_code, child_code, child_rank
   FROM   RecursiveTable
   WHERE  parent_code IN (1, 2, 3)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT r.Root_code, ch.child_code, ch.child_Rank
   FROM   RecursiveTable ch
   JOIN   rekurs r ON ch.parent_code = r.child_code
)
SELECT Root_code, child_code, child_Rank
FROM   rekurs
ORDER BY Root_code
```

This is the result set:

```
Root_code child_code child_Rank
1         2          2
1         3          2
1         4          2
1         7          3
1         5          3
1         6          3
1         8          4
2         5          3
2         6          3
2         8          4
3         7          3
```

Comment: using `IN` will not work for the question especially there are 30000 parents, `IN` can be used for limited values 2100 max I think, so the query will give him an error, also passing the values to SQL, it would be as string, so here you have another performance problem

Comment: @Monah yes you're completely right, I aimed only to showing him how to get more than one tree per call; the IN can be for sure changed to a join or anything else